# QuickBooks test environment

Tags: vb.net, quickbooks

I have QuickBooks running in server mode and it is running fine. I wrote some programs to automate QuickBooks and they are running fine. I would like to expand on my program and the way I currently do it is to:

1. Wait till everyone is out of QuickBooks
2. Restore an old clean database and test my code (Visual Basic)
3. Switch back to the current version (which is time consuming)

Would it be possible to bring up QuickBooks on a second computer and copy the stored files over and then connect to that computer and test my program? This is not an  attempt for me to get around QuickBooks licensing (we have enough), I just do not want to work with live data or stay late at night.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is certainly do-able.

QuickBooks licensing is PER CONCURRENT USER. i.e. You can have QuickBooks installed on as many computers as you want, and have as many company files as you want, AS LONG AS you only have X users *logged into a single company file at any given time* (where X is the # of user licenses you've purchased).